# Identify selected chart in Excel Add-In

Tags: excel, office-js

Is there a way to **identify which chart has the user selected**, parallel to the way to identify the selected range (workbook.getSelectedRange()) in Excel, in an **Office Add-in**?

Further, is there a way to **identify which range the chart** is based on?

I couldn't find anything that would let me do this in the Excel JS API Reference.

Answer (score 2):

No to both. However, they are on our roadmap (no dates yet)

Comment: Has there been any progress in that direction? I would be interested in knowing the value of the data point on click.

Answer (score 1):

Both are in our plan and you should be able to see it soon this year.